# How fast does a Peltier change temperature?

Tags: temperature, thermoelectricity

I am developing a project using peltier element tec1 12706.
I want to achieve a hot side temperature of 60 degrees celsius in a matter of seconds after starting the power.

It's not for an operating machine, it's for a magic trick gimmick and I need heat very quickly for a very small time.

Let's say I provide a 12V 5A electricity - how fast after I start the power will the peltier achieve that temperature starting from it's normal state ?

Also can I achieve better results other voltage and amp numbers ? I just saw that those are the most commonly used.